# Method for displaying the largest of three numbers with the ? operator

Tags: c#, conditional-operator

I've been trying to define a method that should store the largest of three int numbers in a variable and then return that value.

Here's how I tried it:

```
public static int Max(int a, int b, int c)
{
    int iResult = 0;

    a > b && a > c ? iResult = a : b > a && b > c ? iResult = b : iResult = c;
    return(iResult);
}
```

Would be cool if someone could show me why the "?" operator doesn't work :)

Comment: Just `return (a > b && a > c) ? a : ((b > a && b > c) ? b : c);`. Ternary must be **assigned** to some variable or used as returnable value.

Comment: `=> Math.Max(a, Math.Max(b, c));` ?

Comment: When you tell us "it doesn't work", you need to tell us why it doesn't work and what error messages you get. Please take more care with your questions next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`? :` - *ternary operator* - gets **3** arguments and returns one result

```
  iResult = condition ? onTrue : onFalse;
```

In our case we have to combine *two* ternary operators:

```
  iResult = condition1 ? onTrue1 
          : condition2 ? onTrue2
          : onFalse1and2;
```

It can be (please, don't forget about *formatting*, let's keep the code being *readable*)

```
  iResult = a > b && a > c ? a
          : b > a && b > c ? b
          : c;
```

Or we can get rid of `iResult` and put it compact as

```
  public static int Max(int a, int b, int c) =>
      a > b && a > c ? a
    : b > a && b > c ? b
    : c;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
iResult = a > b && a > c ? a : b > a && b > c ? b : c;
```

This thing should work. But also for better understanding you should use braces.

Comment: https://dotnetfiddle.net/cwCMq0 - check it out works